# d3: Text displayed when clicked on leaflet map

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I'm trying get my mouse to show a popup when I click on an geoJSON layer on a leaftlet map. Right now, I just have text displayed on the upper right corner when I hover it over.

The code is below. The error occurs during the function onMapClick (which is mirrored off the Leaflet Quick Start map)

```
      function highlightFeature(e) {
        var layer = e.target;
        layer.setStyle({
          weight: 10,
          color: '#666',
          dashArray: '',
          fillOpacity: 0.5
        });
        if (!L.Browser.ie && !L.Browser.opera) {
          layer.bringToFront();
        }
        info.update(layer.feature.properties);
      }

      var geojson;

      function resetHighlight(e) {
        geojson.resetStyle(e.target);
        info.update();
      }

      var popup = L.popup();
      // ***ERROR BEGINS HERE***
      function onMapClick(e) {
        popup
        //   Ideally I'd want this text to pop up when clicked
        //   This code block to create this text is located towards the end.
        //     '<b>'  + 'Block ID:</b>' + feature.hexid + '<br>'  +
        //     '<b> Population: </b>' + feature.count + '<br>' +
        //     '<b>' + 'Estimated Score: </b>' + feature.score + '<br> ' +
        //     : '');
        // };
          .setContent("Text here " + feature.count)
          .openOn(map);
        }


      function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
          mouseover: highlightFeature,
          mouseout: resetHighlight,
          click: onMapClick //doesn't work 
        });
      }


      geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
        style: style,
        onEachFeature: onEachFeature
      }).addTo(map);


        var info = L.control();
        info.onAdd = function (map) {
          this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info');
          this.update();
          return this._div;
        };
        // this is the text I want displayed on the popup
        info.update = function (feature) {
          this._div.innerHTML = (feature ?
            '<b>'  + 'Block ID:</b>' + feature.hexid + '<br>'  +
            '<b> Population: </b>' + feature.count + '<br>' +
            '<b>' + 'Estimated Score: </b>' + feature.score + '<br> ' +
            : '');
        };
        info.addTo(map);


      };

   </script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I believe your onEachFeature needs a bit of a change.`onMapClick` received an `e`, but you were trying to work on `feature`.
I think you should drop the `onMapClick` and use the below instead.

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
    layer.bindPopup("Text here " + feature.count);
}
```

alongside some other event changes as well.

```
geojson.on('mouseover', highlightFeature)
geojson.on('mouseout', resetHighlight)
```

Comment: Using this method I keep getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined`. I'm new to d3 so I may be implementing it incorrectly.

Comment: Can you update your code block? Even better, put this into a js fiddle.